# Hide a .desktop file on the Desktop [Ubuntu 13.04]

Tags: .desktop

I have made a .desktop launcher for my dock. I try to put a "." after the name of file, but he doesnt hide. Exemple : .Firefox.desktop If i delete it, my Firefox icon in my dock can't be open. I have to hide my desktop file, Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

To show or hide a .desktop file in a given desktop environment we should use its corresponding entry keys:

```
OnlyShowIn=<environment>;
NotShowIn=<environment>;
```

Hence the follwing entry will only show the desktop file in GNOME (e.g. classic), and KDE but not in Unity:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;KDE;
```

Or, alternatively we may wish to define en exclusion with

```
NotShowIn=Unity;
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you renanimg this file? I've noticed that when I rename desktop files using the Nemo file manager (which is used by the third-party "Cinnamon" desktop), the old filename remains present in the terminal (if you open the file using a text editor, the `name=` field changes); I imagine the same would go for the Nautilus manager (which is used by the default desktop, on the regular flavor of Ubuntu).

I would recommend using a terminal to change the file name. Here's an example of how you can do this: `mv /path/to/Firefox.desktop /path/to/.Firefox.desktop`. You can simply replace the /path/to part with the path to the Firefox.desktop file (unless of course you prefer to use cd to move straight to that directory).

Or, you could open the file with any text editor, and use the "Save As" function to create a new file with a new name, and then delete the original file.